# Scraping website with credentials using scrapy issue with FORMDATA

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, scrapy, form-data

Hope everyone is safe and sound,
I am currently training on scrapy and decided to try scraping a website (Glassdoor) that requires logins.
I am stuck and wonder if anyone could check what I have done so far and give me a hand?

1)I loaded the glassdoor login page and open the inspect tool (in Chrome), 
2)Selected the Network section and enter my logins in the page, once logged I looked for the login_input.htm file with a 302 status (POST) once selected I got into the the HEADER section but I cannot not find the FORMDATA section. So I do not have all the information to add in my code.

I tried a lot of online resources but cannot find a solution to this?

I also placed the code I started to work with:

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.http import FormRequest
    from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


    class GdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'gd'
        allowed_domains = ['https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/profile/login_input.htm']
        start_urls = ('http://https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/profile/login_input.htm/',)

        def parse(self, response):
            return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                     formdata={'password': 'mypassword',
                                               'username': 'myusername'},
                                     callback=self.scrape_pages)

        def scrape_pages(self, response):
            open_in_browser(response)
```

Could anyone let me know what I did wrong please?

Thank you,

Arnaud

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show the error that you received when running your code

Comment: @Hack5  Hi Hack5 thank you for getting back to me and thank you for welcoming me. I did more digging as I did not want to let this go and decided to go through every file in the network and finally found the correct login file with the FORM DATA I needed. The code work all good now. Thanks again for taking time to help me, I really appreciate. Best, A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glasdoor's login is a JavaScript rendered popup, if you disable JS you will see that nothing renders when you try to click the Sign In link or opening the link you have given.

This seems to be what you are looking for:
`https://www.glassdoor.com/profile/ajax/loginAjax.htm`
when you open the Sign In popup and try to login using any credentials (can be wrong, does not matter), you will see `loginAjax.htm` pop up in the Network tab. This one has a form that sends credentials by POST to the link I posted above.

Unfortunately it also does send a token with the credentials, so using this to log in might prove difficult.

For sending data you can use `_urlencode` from `from scrapy.http.request.form import _urlencode` like this:

```
inputs = [("key", "value"),]
body = _urlencode(inputs, response.encoding)
```

and send the `body` via POST to the above URL (inputs have to be a list of tuples) building a normal Scrapy Request.

Comment: Hi Bartek, Thank you very much for getting back to me and for your help. I did more digging and went through all the files one by one until I found the one with a form data section. You are right loginAjax.htm was the correct one. Thank you for the code snippet you sent I will work on this now. Thank you again for your help.